# SQL Query to concatenate column values from multiple rows in Oracle with count

Tags: oracle, aggregate-functions

> I have below oracle table:

```
Table A

PID   SEQ    Desc

A     1      Have
A     2      a nice
A     3      day.
B     1      Nice Work.
C     1      Yes
C     2      we can 
C     3      do 
C     4      this work!
```

> I want to aggregate Output of the table such that it should be -

```
PID   Desc1                          Desc2
A     Have a nice day.               Have
A     Have a nice day.               a nice
A     Have a nice day.               day!
B     Nice Work.                     Nice Work.
C     Yes we can do this work!       Yes
C     Yes we can do this work!       we can
C     Yes we can do this work!       do
C     Yes we can do this work!       this work!
```

> Notice that SEQ column determines order of desc aggregation. I have tried below query:

```
SELECT pid, LISTAGG(Desc, ' ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY seq) AS description
FROM B GROUP BY pid;
```

> Which got me this result:

```
PID   Desc
A     Have a nice day.
B     Nice Work.
C     Yes we can do this work!
```

> I am not sure how to get the desired result. Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `LISTAGG` as an analytic function rather than an aggregation function:

```sql
SELECT pid,
       LISTAGG(descr, ' ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY seq) OVER (PARTITION BY pid)
         AS description,
       descr
FROM   table_a
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Table_A (PID, SEQ, Descr) AS
SELECT 'A', 1, 'Have'       FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 2, 'a nice'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 3, 'day.'       FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 1, 'Nice Work.' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C', 1, 'Yes'        FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C', 2, 'we can'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C', 3, 'do'         FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C', 4, 'this work!' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| PID | DESCRIPTION | DESCR |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Have a nice day. | Have |
| A | Have a nice day. | a nice |
| A | Have a nice day. | day. |
| B | Nice Work. | Nice Work. |
| C | Yes we can do this work! | Yes |
| C | Yes we can do this work! | we can |
| C | Yes we can do this work! | do |
| C | Yes we can do this work! | this work! |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/0B7CaBjM)

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to repeat the returning rows as many as the rows exist within the table `a`. To do this, just apply cross join the table `a` with the subquery you currently have such as

```
WITH bb AS
(
  SELECT pid, LISTAGG("Desc", ' ') WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY seq ) AS desc1
    FROM b
   GROUP BY pid
)
SELECT a.pid, bb.desc1, "Desc" AS desc2
  FROM a
 CROSS JOIN bb
 WHERE bb.pid = a.pid
 ORDER BY seq
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `model` clause and `listagg` aggregate function as a right hand side of the rule with reference to all dimension values (`any` in the script below). `seq as seq_new` is exposed as a separate measure to allow it's usage inside `within group`.

```
select
  pid,
  seq,
  descr_new
from tablea
model
  partition by(pid)
  dimension by(seq)
  measures(descr, descr as descr_new, seq as seq_new)
  rules update (
    descr_new[any] = listagg(descr, ' ') within group(order by seq_new)[any]
  )
```

| PID | SEQ | DESCR_NEW |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | Have a nice day. |
| A | 2 | Have a nice day. |
| A | 3 | Have a nice day. |
| B | 1 | Nice Work. |
| C | 1 | Yes we can do this work! |
| C | 2 | Yes we can do this work! |
| C | 3 | Yes we can do this work! |
| C | 4 | Yes we can do this work! |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/fR_TIUt9)